# c# printing date-- Latin letters instead of the date

Tags: c#, date, printing

This is my code:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    string s = string.Format("name: {0} , Date: {1}, Salary: {2}, id {3}", name, startDate.ToShortDateString(), salary, id);
    return s;
}
```

When I run it
it prints Latin letters instead of the date.

Comment: Can you please show the latin letters.

Comment: What is your system locale?

Comment: How do i copy while running the program?

Answer (score 0):

Check current culture of your program, this may be the reason of the problem you're having:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    Console.WriteLine(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    Console.WriteLine(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture);

    string s = string.Format("name: {0} , Date: {1}, Salary: {2}, id {3}", name, startDate.ToShortDateString(), salary, id);
    return s;
}
```

Here is some more info on this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hh873ya(v=vs.90).aspx

Also, you can format the date explicitly:

```
string s = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "name: {0} , Date: {1:yyyy/MM/dd}, Salary: {2}, id {3}", name, startDate, salary, id);
```

`CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` parameter is not necessary, only if it is not used then in some cases '/' character will be replaced by the date separator of the currently set culture ('-' for example). It also should be noted that the decimal separator for invariant culture is a dot, and there is no thousand separator. If you want to format numbers (for example the 'salary' variable) in a different way (consistent with the culture set in your application) then you should format the date separately:

```
string dateString = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:yyyy/MM/dd}", startDate);
string s = string.Format("name: {0} , Date: {1}, Salary: {2}, id {3}", name, dateString, salary, id);
```